# how to do click random motion animation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an animation like an object have to move randomly and whenever someone clicks on the object(in this case it a div) the object should hit the edges of the browser and come back smoothly and again start moving randomly(hope you are getting my point) I have been surfing the internet from past few days to how to do this by means of any library or by custom coding but I didn't figure out the answer.

I tried to do it on my own but didn't succeed.
Here is my code

```js
let test = document.querySelector(".test");
test.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  
  let check = e.offsetX
  switch(true){
      case(e.offsetX <= this.offsetWidth / 6):
      console.log("its above 50")
      gsap.to(".test",{x:window.innerWidth/2.7,y:50})
      break;
      case(e.offsetX <= this.offsetWidth / 3):
      console.log("its above 100")
      break;
      case(e.offsetX <= this.offsetWidth / 2):
      console.log("its above 150")
      gsap.to(".test",{/* x:window.innerWidth/2.7 */y:50})
      break;
      case(e.offsetX <= this.offsetWidth / 1.5):
      console.log("its above 200")
      break;
      case(e.offsetX <= this.offsetWidth / 1.2):
      console.log("its above 250")
      gsap.to(".test",{x:0-(window.innerWidth/2.7),y:50})
      break;
   }
  
   console.log(e.clientX)  
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.bgcolor {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.test{
  width:300px;
  height:210px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  
}
.check{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:105px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="test test1" style="background:#FCD757;" >
 </div>
```

Comment: Actually after seeing the border sol u posted it blew my mind and forced me solve this question  :-)

Comment: An advice is to read through this entire documentation (everything about javascript), but here they specifically talk about collision in 2D space:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: @Sanmeet What blew your mind

Comment: I never thought it could be possible to make cool border with just css .. what I thought was using svgs to make it happen ......
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712043/is-it-possible-to-achieve-a-curved-circle-shape-using-border-radius/66712500#66712500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple bounce of the walls and changing direction when clicked:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e =>
{
  const test = document.getElementById("test"),
        rect = test.getBoundingClientRect(),
        rectBox = test.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
        xMax = rectBox.width + rectBox.x - rect.width,
        yMax = rectBox.height + rectBox.y - rect.height,
        maxSpeed = 1;

  let x = rect.x,
      y = rect.y,
      xDelta,
      yDelta;

  setSpeed();
  test.addEventListener("click", setSpeed);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
  test.classList.toggle("move", true);
  function move(timestamp)
  {
    x = x + xDelta;
    y = y + yDelta;
    if (x < rectBox.x || x > xMax)
    {
      xDelta = -xDelta;
      x = x < rectBox.x ? rectBox.x : xMax;
    }
    if (y < rectBox.y || y > yMax)
    {
      yDelta = -yDelta;
      y = y < rectBox.y ? rectBox.y : yMax;
    }
    
    test.style.left = x + "px";
    test.style.top = y + "px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
  };
  function setSpeed()
  {
    xDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
    yDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
  }
  function rand(min, max)
  {
    return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
  }
});
```

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
.box
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.bgcolor {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.test
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background-color: #FCD757;
  
}
.test.move
{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.check{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="test" class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man for improving my code ! Can you tell me what a code snippet  ( run code snippet )  ?

Comment: Code snippet allows see the code in action in the answer itself.

Comment: @vanowm Thanks a lot for this answer could you tell me why there are many commas in the javascript const = test and what they do. If this question seems useful you can upvote this

Comment: Instead of using `const`, `let` or `var` for each variable, we can define multiple variables by separating them with a comma.

Comment: Thanks a lot please don't mind I have another question because Now I am trying to understand the logic of this animation. and what is mean by .test.move in CSS and if it is possible could you make me understand the logic of all that animation it will be convenient for me to perceive this.

Comment: @vanowm Sir can you tell me how to rotate this div at its own axis while moving and also I wanna know that how to do with many objects when they collide they change their direction

Comment: @vanowm Sir I have rotated these boxes but there is a problem they are going out of the container So can you help me out how fix this Here is the question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066592/objects-going-out-of-container-while-rotation-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Using  Math.random() method i created 2 values and adjusted them accordingly  , inorder to make them more sensible ( not moving outside div element ).
After that i used setInterval method  and stored it in global variable to set it again or clear it using clearInterval method.
Finally created moveAtSpecifiedPos function helps you to set the position when it is clicked

Change the attributes of the div with class ball to figure out animation speeds and smoothness !
One thing I really was not able to figure out how to make collision at right time using js

```js
 
 // getting ball and ball contained div
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

const ball_div = document.querySelector('.moveObj');

let animation_time, transition_type, restart_time;

animation_time = ball.getAttribute("data-animation-time");
transition_type = ball.getAttribute("data-transition-type");
restart_time = ball.getAttribute("data-resart-time");

ball.style.transition = `${animation_time} ${transition_type}`;


// getting main div's height and width in which ball moves
let  max_movement_height = ball_div.scrollHeight;
let max_movement_width = ball_div.scrollWidth;

let ball_half_height = ball.scrollHeight / 2;


let top_wall = (max_movement_height / 2 - ball_half_height);
let bottom_wall = -1*(top_wall);
let right_wall = (max_movement_width/2 - ball_half_height);
let left_wall = -1*(right_wall);

let intveral, num;

wall__sides = {
  top: top_wall+"px",
  bottom: bottom_wall+"px",
  left: left_wall+"px",
  right: right_wall+"px"
};


function start_animtion() {

  interval = setInterval(function () {

    num = Math.round(randomNumber(0, 100));
    if (num !== num % 2) {
      move_X = Math.round(randomNumber(1, 2)) == 1 ? wall__sides.left: wall__sides.right;
    } else {
      move_X = randomNumber(parseInt(wall__sides.left), parseInt(wall__sides.right)) + "px";

    }
    if (num === num % 2) {
      move_Y = Math.round(randomNumber(1, 2)) == 1 ? wall__sides.top: wall__sides.bottom;
    } else {
      move_Y = randomNumber(parseInt(wall__sides.bottom), parseInt(wall__sides.top)) + "px";
    }

    ball.style.transform = `translate(${ move_X} , ${move_Y})`;
  },
    parseInt(animation_time));

}
function finish_animation() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  moveAtSpecifiedPos();
  setTimeout(function() {
    ball.innerText = "catch me ";
    start_animtion();
  },
    parseInt(restart_time));
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {

  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function moveAtSpecifiedPos() {
  ball.innerText = "caught";
  ball.style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
}

start_animtion();
```

```css
    
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.moveObj {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ball {
  --width: 100px;
  --height: 100px;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  width: px;
  background: white;
  top: calc(50% - var(--height) / 2 );
  left: calc(50% -  var(--width) / 2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="moveObj">
  <div class="ball" onclick="finish_animation()" data-resart-time="2000ms" data-transition-type="ease" data-animation-time="400ms"> Catch me </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot for this answer I will do this for multiple items and how do I make this animation smoother because the animation is not that much smooth and the click is not working and it is not also not colliding with walls. if this question seems useful you can upvote this.

Comment: Updated my answer now it will prevent the ball from moving out of the div  ... Also try using species paths instead of using math random as it will lead to weird behaviour ....

Answer (score 1):

Pass event on click into a function, then set you collision variables and check them in conditionals. You can use CSS variables for the animations and set them using javascript with the document.documentElement.

```js
let test = document.querySelector(".test")

function moveBox(e){
  const root = document.documentElement;
  const winTop = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
  const winBot = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
  const winLeft = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left
  const winRight = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().right
  let xpos = e.offsetX
  let ypos = e.offsetY
  const box = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  const widthCenter = box.width - (box.width / 2)
  const heightCenter = box.height - (box.height / 2)
  const disFromTop = window.pageYOffset + e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top
  const disFromBot = window.pageYOffset + e.target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - box.height
  const disFromLeft = window.pageXOffset + e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left
  const disFromRight = window.pageXOffset + e.target.getBoundingClientRect().right - box.width
  // should equal the animations duration as set in CSS
  const duration = 500;
  let left = false,
    right = false,
    up = false,
    down = false;
  xpos < widthCenter ? left = true : right = true
  ypos < heightCenter ? up = true : down = true

  const classNames = ['animateLeft', 'animateRight', 'animateUp', 'animateDown']
  const rootClass = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom']

  if (left === true && xpos < ypos && xpos < e.target.clientHeight - ypos) {
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[0]}Anim`, `${winLeft}px`)
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[0]}`, `${disFromLeft}px`)
    e.target.classList.add(classNames[0])
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.classList.remove(classNames[0])
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[0]}Anim`)
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[0]}`)
    }, duration)
  }
  if (right === true && e.target.clientWidth - xpos < ypos && e.target.clientWidth - xpos < e.target.clientHeight - ypos) {
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[1]}Anim`, `${winRight}px`)
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[1]}`, `${disFromRight}px`)
    e.target.classList.add(classNames[1])
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.classList.remove(classNames[1])
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[1]}Anim`)
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[1]}`)
    }, duration)
  }
  if (up === true && xpos > ypos && ypos < e.target.clientWidth - xpos) {
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[2]}Anim`, `${winTop}px`)
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[2]}`, `${disFromTop}px`)
    e.target.classList.add(classNames[2])
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.classList.remove(classNames[2])
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[2]}Anim`)
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[2]}`)
    }, duration)
  }
  if (down === true && xpos > e.target.clientHeight - ypos && e.target.clientHeight - ypos < e.target.clientWidth - xpos) {
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[3]}Anim`, `${root.clientHeight - box.height}px`)
    root.style.setProperty(`--${rootClass[3]}`, `${disFromBot}px`)
    e.target.classList.add(classNames[3])
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.classList.remove(classNames[3])
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[3]}Anim`)
      root.style.removeProperty(`--${rootClass[3]}`)
    }, duration)
  }
}

test.addEventListener("click", moveBox)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 /* added */
:root {
  --width: 100px;
  --height: 100px;
  --leftAnim: 0;
  --rightAnim: 0;
  --topAnim: 0;
  --bottomAnim: 0;
  --left: calc(50% - 50px);
  --right: calc(50% - 50px);
  --top: calc(50% - 50px);
  --bottom: calc(50% - 50px);
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.bgcolor {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--top);
  left: var(--left);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.check {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 105px;
}
 /* added */
.animateLeft {
  animation: moveLeft .5s ease-in-out;
}
 /* added */
.animateRight {
  animation: moveRight .5s ease-in-out;
}
 /* added */
.animateUp {
  animation: moveUp .5s ease-in-out;
}
 /* added */
.animateDown {
  animation: moveDown .5s ease-in-out;
}
 /* added */
@keyframes moveLeft {
  0% {
    left: var(--left);
  }
  70% {
    left: var(--leftAnim);
  }
  100% {
    left: var(--left)
  }
}
 /* added */
@keyframes moveRight {
  0% {
    left: var(--right);
  }
  70% {
    left: calc(var(--rightAnim) - var(--width));
  }
  100% {
    left: var(--right);
  }
}
 /* added */
@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    top: var(--top);
  }
  70% {
    top: var(--topAnim);
  }
  100% {
    top: var(--top)
  }
}
 /* added */
@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    top: var(--bottom);
  }
  70% {
    top: var(--bottomAnim);
  }
  100% {
    top: var(--bottom)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="test test1" style="background:#FCD757;">
</div>
```