# Objects going out of container while rotation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animation like there are some boxes (actually they are divs) that are moving randomly and if any box hits with the walls of the parent container they bounce back and change their direction, everything works fine till here. The problem comes when I  give the rotation to the boxes, by giving the rotation the boxes are going out of the parent container and not colliding with the walls of the parent container.
So I want to know why this is happening and how to fix that like boxes have to collide with the walls container while rotating.

Here is my code

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {

  const test = document.querySelectorAll(".test")
  
  test.forEach(function(many) {

    let rect = many.getBoundingClientRect(),
      rectBox = many.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
      xMax = rectBox.width + rectBox.x - rect.width,
      yMax = rectBox.height + rectBox.y - rect.height,
      maxSpeed = 1;

    let x = rect.x,
      y = rect.y,
      xDelta,
      yDelta;

    setSpeed();
    many.addEventListener("click", setSpeed);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    many.classList.toggle("move", true);

    function move(timestamp) {
      x = x + xDelta;
      y = y + yDelta;
      if (x < rectBox.x || x > xMax) {
        xDelta = -xDelta;
        x = x < rectBox.x ? rectBox.x : xMax;
      }
      if (y < rectBox.y || y > yMax) {
        yDelta = -yDelta;
        y = y < rectBox.y ? rectBox.y : yMax;
      }
      many.style.transform = `rotate(${x/2}deg)`
      many.style.left = x + "px";
      many.style.top = y + "px";
      window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    };
    //console.log(xDelta)

    function setSpeed() {
      xDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
      yDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
    }

    function rand(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    }

  })

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.bgcolor {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #FCD757;
}

.move {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.check {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 105px;
}

.big {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="test" class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The equations when calculating collisions of rotated boxes are not equal to equations of  unrotated boxes, you've to take the rotation angle in the calculations too.

Comment: @Teemu Sir could you please give me  a demo

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to create a demo. I believe you can find a solution, treat the box as four lines, and calculate if a line crosses the border if at all.

Comment: @Teemu Sir I can understand that you are busy but could you tell me what do you mean by  "treat the box as four lines"

Comment: The box is built of four lines which border the box. You need to calculate the end points (certain corners of the box) of the rotated line, then check if any corner hits any of the four borders. You can also search for how to calculate the collisions of two boxes at https://math.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:relative;` from `.box` class. It will contain the boxes within the parent, however because `rect` is used outside of `move` function it contains non-rotated dimensions of the box which does not properly render box collision:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {

  const test = document.querySelectorAll(".test")
  
  test.forEach(function(many) {

    let rect = many.getBoundingClientRect(),
      rectBox = many.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
      xMax = rectBox.width + rectBox.x - rect.width,
      yMax = rectBox.height + rectBox.y - rect.height,
      maxSpeed = 1;
//dotted box
const boundBox = document.createElement("div");
boundBox.className = "boundBox";
boundBox.addEventListener("click", setSpeed);
document.body.appendChild(boundBox);

    let x = rect.x,
      y = rect.y,
      xDelta,
      yDelta;

    setSpeed();
    many.addEventListener("click", setSpeed);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    many.classList.toggle("move", true);

    function move(timestamp) {
      x = x + xDelta;
      y = y + yDelta;
      if (x < rectBox.x || x > xMax) {
        xDelta = -xDelta;
        x = x < rectBox.x ? rectBox.x : xMax;
      }
      if (y < rectBox.y || y > yMax) {
        yDelta = -yDelta;
        y = y < rectBox.y ? rectBox.y : yMax;
      }
      many.style.transform = `rotate(${x/2}deg)`
      many.style.left = x + "px";
      many.style.top = y + "px";

boundBox.style.left = x + "px";
boundBox.style.top = y + "px";
boundBox.style.width = rect.width + "px";
boundBox.style.height = rect.height + "px";

      window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    };
    //console.log(xDelta)

    function setSpeed() {
      xDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
      yDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
    }

    function rand(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    }

  })

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
/*  position: relative;*/
  margin-top: 50px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.bgcolor {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #FCD757;
}

.move {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.check {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 105px;
}

.big {
  width: 120px;
}

.boundBox
{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="test" class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

To fix that, we need to get box `rect` for each frame and for both before and after it was rotated:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e =>
{
  const test = document.querySelectorAll(".test");

  test.forEach(function(many){
    
    
    const rectBox = many.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
          rect = many.getBoundingClientRect(),
          maxSpeed = 1;

//dotted box
const boundBox = document.createElement("div");
boundBox.className = "boundBox";
boundBox.addEventListener("click", setSpeed);
document.body.appendChild(boundBox);

    let x = rect.x,
        y = rect.y,
        xDelta,
        yDelta;

    setSpeed();
    many.addEventListener("click", setSpeed);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    many.parentNode.classList.toggle("move", true);
    function move(timestamp)
    {
      x = x + xDelta;
      y = y + yDelta;

      many.style.transform = "";
      const rectInit = many.getBoundingClientRect();

      many.style.transform = `rotate(${x/2}deg)`;
      const rectBox = many.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
            rect = many.getBoundingClientRect(),
            xDif = rect.x - rectInit.x,
            yDif = rect.y - rectInit.y,
            xMin = rectBox.x - xDif,
            yMin = rectBox.y - yDif,
            xMax = rectBox.width + rectBox.x - rect.width - xDif,
            yMax = rectBox.height + rectBox.y - rect.height - yDif;

      if (x < xMin || x > xMax)
      {
        xDelta = -xDelta;
        x = x < xMin ? xMin : xMax;
      }
      if (y < yMin || y > yMax)
      {
        yDelta = -yDelta;
        y = y < yMin ? yMin : yMax;
      }
      many.style.left = x + "px";
      many.style.top = y + "px";

boundBox.style.left = x + xDif + "px";
boundBox.style.top = y + yDif + "px";
boundBox.style.width = rect.width + "px";
boundBox.style.height = rect.height + "px";

      window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
    } //move()
    //console.log(xDelta)


    function setSpeed()
    {
      xDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
      yDelta = rand(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
    }
    function rand(min, max)
    {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    }

  }) //forEach
    
});
```

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}
.box
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
/*  position:relative;*/
  margin-top: 50px;

}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.bgcolor {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.test
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background-color: #FCD757;
  
}
.move .test
{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.check{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:105px;
}
.big{
  width:120px;
}

.boundBox
{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="test" class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test big"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your answer But why these boxes have loosed their clickability and How to make them clickable again.

Comment: Oh, it's due to additional `boundBox`. Fixed it.

Comment: May I know why it is outside the box when it is viewed on full screen? https://nimb.ws/hwqKX7 Part of the answer?

Comment: Because the container dimensions `rectBox` are taken only once during first initialization. Fixed.

Comment: @vanowm There is another awsome question Could you help me out with that Because you resolved my issue of floating objects which I thought was impossible with pure JS.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207471/how-to-created-paper-folding-effect-in-css-and-javascript