# How to create paper folding effect in Css and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a paper-folding effect through CSS and Javascript like it has to interact with the mouse but I tried to do this but didn't figure it out. And I also surfed on the internet but there is no trace of how to do this. The effect must be like this [Netrix Digital](https://netrixdigital.com/).

So can anyone tell me how to do this and if you paste the answer please make sure to explain it.

Here is my code

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.bgcolor {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.fold{
  width:500px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fold h1{
  line-height:350px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fold">
    <h1>Folding effect</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping in advance :)

Comment: does this help? [CodePen: Paper Fold Effect](https://codepen.io/muhamidelsayed/pen/rjyMaM)

Comment: @AhsanKhan NO! Because first of all, it is fully not interactive like the site example which I have given and secondly JS should be used and there is no explanation also.

Comment: if anyone is downvoting tell the reason also.

Comment: You may hover over the downwards triangle, if you are not familiar with valid downvote reasons. You just told us what you want (and even that in a sub-optimal way only, because when that external page changes at any point in the future, the question will likely lose context and thereby any value to future readers), there is no effort shown here, no research effort either - this is just one of those typical “hey I have no clue but massive ambitions, and now I need you to write or find a tutorial for me” questions to me.

Comment: You could try a [javascript library](http://www.turnjs.com/).

Comment: @CBroe As I said I have no idea how it is done so how I do provide the research and there is no trace on the internet of that effect

Comment: Not every question you might have, _belongs_ here in the first place. Asking us for plugin or tutorial recommendations for example, would be explicitly considered off-topic here. And expecting someone to explain the whole thing for you from start to finish - well that would basically be asking to write a tutorial _for you_. You people should learn to let your ambitions to grow together with your skill set, instead of letting the former overtake the latter all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps ->

[CodePen Link to Paper Folding Effect](https://codepen.io/muhamidelsayed/pen/rjyMaM)

HTML ->

```
<div class="fold"></div>
```

CSS ->

```
    body {
  background: #344;
  padding: 25px
}
/* paper */
.fold {
  postion: relative;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #fff
}
/* folding */
.fold::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 100px 100px 0;
  border-color: #ddd #344;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
.fold:hover::before {
  border-width: 0 150px 150px 0;
  border-color: #eee #344
}
```